# XMLHttpRequest to jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have this code and I want it using jQuery Ajax.

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0], file, target, i, len;
input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    target = e.target.files;

    for (i = 0, len = target.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        file = target[i];
    }
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', file);
    console.log(fd);


    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('POST', "https://api.imgur.com/3/image", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                var response = '';
                try {
                    response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                } catch (err) {
                    response = this.responseText;
                }
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                throw new Error(this.status + " - " + this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.send(fd);
    xhttp = null;
});
```

I already tried it make myself but it did not work.

Code I have tried:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/image",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
            'Authorization':'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      },
      data: fd,
      success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
      }
});
```

But logs error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

It worked if I delete `data: fd`, but data is required.

Comment: I guess you have problems setting the header? Because using `$.post('url', function() {/* on success*/})` is pretty straightforward.

Comment: would you mind provide the code you have tried so far ?

Comment: Have you been through the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

Comment: @Al.G. No I had problem with data.

Comment: @moein rahimi Of course! Im gonna edit post.

Comment: @kidA Yes but nothing worked :(

Comment: Your question now seems to be "How to send files via jQuery ajax". Am I right? You'd spare us and yourself a lot of time if you asked this still in the beginning.

Comment: @Al.G. No. I just wanted to "conver" code... Just you didn't see that it contains data too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
    method: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Client-ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' },
    success: function(data){
        //do your parsing here
    }
});
```

Comment: Tip: use `$.post(...)` and leave out the `method` property.

Comment: `$.post` gives you less flexibility in terms of setting up callback handlers unless you use `$.ajaxSetup` which will affect all your ajax requests. I would suggest sticking to `$.ajax` for a more controllable flow.

Comment: Does it? According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-settings): _See jQuery.ajax( settings ) for a complete list of all settings. Type will automatically be set to POST._ - which implies that the `settings` object is the same as for `$.ajax()`.

Comment: @sh4dowb Im need to send data `fd` at the end `xhttp.send(fd)`, it is not very good visible.

Comment: @sh4dowb I have edited my post too and have same code as you. Still the same error :/

Comment: @MataxePlay so it seems jquery parses data if processData is not false. as it's not a parseable data, it throws error. i've edited it again

Comment: @sh4dowb Hmm.. Now it works but server returns Error 500 (Internal Server Error)... (with original code it still works well)